# NextJS: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asset')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

While building a forked NextJS repo, the following errors occur:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/en-us/about-us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asset')

Error occurred prerendering page "/en-au/about-us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asset')

Error occurred prerendering page "/en-uk/about-us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asset')

Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /[slug]: /en-au/about-us
        /[slug]: /en-gb/about-us
        /[slug]: /en-us/about-us
```

The original website repo does not have this build error.

The original SanityCMS project was copied to a new project and connected to this forked NextJS website.

I have not altered the three about us pages in the new SanityCMS project or altered `/pages/[slug].tsx` in the forked NextJS website.

The only changes I've made to the forked NextJS repo are in:

`/components/navigationItems.tsx`, adding some `<SingleImage {...image} />` which are created in SanityCMS > Settings > Navigation.

None of those header navigation images are broken in SanityCMS or any front-end web pages, and the three About Us pages have not had their SanityCMS content edited, and `/pages/[slug].tsx` has not been edited.

Why might the asset errors occur for the three about-us pages?

BTW, searching the forked website in VS Code for `asset`:

[image]

there are plenty of media assets being used. However, `navigationItems.tsx` is the only file that has changed on the website, and `asset` is not used in this file.

So where might this `asset` problem come from?

Help appreciated.

Comment: can you share the code snippet

Comment: you can put your assets under the public/<asset> and then try to access it

Comment: `asset` might be an environment variable? Ask the repo owner about this. If it's not in the code, it's probably something related to the production environment

Comment: Thanks @sanjarcode `asset` is not an environment variable